# Keep the collection always fixed to certain number

Tags: magento-1.8, product-collection, best-practice

I am using the following code to get **five** Best sellers collection. The number **five** is fixed here.

```
// Array of Id's to retrieve from product collection
$dataArray = array(2, 8 , 17, 3, 7);
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
        ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $dataArray)
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
// shuffling the retrieved collection
$collection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));
// limiting the collection to number 5
$collection->setPageSize(5);
```

`$dataArray` is a variable which holds the product ids.

In above code, the `$dataArray` can have **less than five ids**. In those cases, I am getting the collection less than five. But my requirement is that the collection **must have five products** even the `$dataArray` holds less than 5 values. I mean the remaining product collection should come from the same Bestsellers collection excluding the `$dataArray` values.

How should I do this?

I can do this something like this, which I think is not good for performance:

```
 $count = count($collection);
 if($count < 5){
     $remainingCount = 5 - $count;
     // Again run the above product collection
     // exclude the product ids which are already present in array
     // setPageSize to $remainingCount
     // and somehow merge the above specific best sellers with this 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the same and exclude the IDs:

```
$remainingCount = 5 - $count;
// Array of Id's to retrieve from product collection
$dataArray = array(2, 8 , 17, 3, 7);
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
        ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $dataArray)
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
// shuffling the retrieved collection
$collection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));
// limiting the collection to number 5
$collection->setPageSize($remainingCount);
// exclude the IDs
$collection->setAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('nin' => $dataArray));
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do the attribute filtering to the already attribute filtered collection (_two times with `entity_id`_). I am getting error when I tried your code. `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::setAttributeToFilter()`

Comment: Oh no, you need to shot a second collection, sorry. and the method name is addAttributeToFilter, sorry.